# Убрать ссылку саму на себя.

Tags: php

Есть навигация:

```
<a href='?menu'>Меню</a> 
<a href='?info'>Информация</a> 
<a href='?help'>Помощь</a>
```

Нужно что бы ссылка которая ведет сама на себя отличалась от остальных. Допустим мы находимся в 'Информации', то ссылка в навигации ведущая на информацию отличалась от остальных ссылок. Как реализовать на PHP, подскажите пожалуйста. PS с CSS сам разберусь.

Comment: начинать надо с того, что ссылки "сама на себя" не должно быть в принципе. [ководство §75](http://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/75/)

Comment: думаю, что аудитория не покинет мой проект из за столь незначительной оплошности, маркер на ссылке в самый раз дабы не запутать пользователя

Comment: @yura-ivanov поклоняйтесь дальше Лебедеву. С его ужасными интерфейсами.

Comment: @lampa такое ощущение, что вы хотели меня как-то задеть. я обязательно прислушаюсь к вашему мнению, даже запишу. спасибо!

Comment: @Yura Ivanov я скорее за пользователей ваших сайтов беспокоюсь.

Comment: @lampa и за заботу отдельное спасибо. вам срочно надо написать в яндекс и передать им что вы беспокоитесь об их сайте, там нельзя нажать на поиск на странице поиска, а на картах ссылку карт! ужас-ужас.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov тролль из вас никакой, скорее истеричка :D На картах ссылка не нужна, т.к. страница не нуждается в обновлении. Ваш К.О.

Answer (score 3):

Тут всё просто на самом деле.

Так как вы знаете, какой у Вас модуль сейчас должен функционировать, установите его имя, допустим в тэг `body` (ex. `<body class="info|help|menu"...`). А вот уже с помощью css скрывайте или выделяйте текущий пункт. ex:

```
body.info > a#info {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Сделал проще. В подключаемом меню - <a href='?menu' class='menu <?=$menu_actve ?>'>Меню</a> 
<a href='?info' class='menu <?=$info_actve ?>'>Информация</a> 
<a href='?help' class='menu <?=$help_actve ?>'>Помощь</a>. В стилях класс menu содержит color:green;, а класс acive, color:red;. В каждом файле до вызова меню просто присваиваю уникальной переменной значение 'active'.
```

Comment: только я бы ещё и пробел внёс в $info_actve, чтобы если класс ставить не нужно у Вас бы не получилось так class='menu '

Comment: Так это так и продумано, если переменная не задано, то работает menu. Поправка: класс не active, а menu active

Comment: неайс) посмотрите мой код ;)

Answer (score 2):

Можно как-то так:

```
<style>
.selected-link{color:gray;}
</style>
<a href='?menu'<?if(isset($_GET['menu'])):?> class="selected-link"<?endif?>>Меню</a> 
<a href='?info'<?if(isset($_GET['info'])):?> class="selected-link"<?endif?>>Информация</a> 
<a href='?help'<?if(isset($_GET['help'])):?> class="selected-link"<?endif?>>Помощь</a>
```

Comment: Очень громоздкое решение.

Comment: @lampa Да, громоздкое, но оно достаточно простое, чтобы тот кто придет в проект после вас, с первого взгляда понял что оно делает. ИМХО это очень важный фактор)))

Comment: Я бы вот выругался как следует, увидя такой код. Лучше довести до ума, потратив чуточку больше времени, так сказать скилл-то прибавляться всё равно будет. 

Я примерно так вижу:
http://pastebin.com/xAtEYuZG

Конечно тоже не идеальное, но по красивее как-то смотрится :)

Comment: @lampa Понятно, у нас с вами принципиально разные понятия красоты кода. Свой вариант я тоже ниразу не считаю красивым, но ваш, да еще и c регуляркой. Ууу, ИМХО жуть :) Уж если говорить о красоте решения, то мне кажется вариант предложенный @stck оптимален. Но он не KISS, имхо)

Comment: Можно, конечно, и без регулярки обойтись. Да не суть, вариантов решения этой задачи овер9000. Кстати, говорить об оптимальности варианта @stck думаю не верно, т.к. не известно, что подставляет класс в body :)

Comment: @lampa, мой вариант убог для динамически-конструируемых меню

Answer (score 0):

Вот:

```
<?php
$array = array('menu', 'info', 'help');

if(preg_match('/('.implode('+|', $array).'+)(?:$|=|&)/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $match)) {
        $menu_class = $match[1];
}

?>
<style>
.menu .<?=$menu_class?> {
        color: red;
}
</style>

<div class='menu'>
        <a href='#' class='info'>link</a>
        <a href='#' class='menu'>link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>

var active_menu = "<?=$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']?>";
$("a."+active_menu).addClass("active");

</script>

<div class='menu'>
        <a href='#' class='info'>link</a>
        <a href='#' class='menu'>link</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Жестоко откритикую вас! Во первых ваш способ не рабочий ;) dom.ready дядя Федор будет подставлять? 
Давайте дальше. Если я добавлю в QUERY_STRING еще какие-то символы? 
А если тс вообще не использует jQuery в проекте? Не подключать же целую библиотеку для вот такой милипизерной задачи.
А если меню находится вверху сайта? Подсветка же не сразу сработает. 
Про поисковики я вообще молчу. Анкор просто не обработается должным образом. С наилучшими пожеланиями :)

Comment: /?';alert('Tada');'


Да и вообще сомнительный подход. К примеру на страничке /?info&page=2 уже не сработает как положено

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но читайте внимательней вопрос " Как реализовать на PHP".

Comment: @lampa ну так делать за когото полностью вообще неправильно) главное задать верное направление. этот пример нельзя использвоать as is хотябы по соображениям безопасности ;) дополню Вашу критику: а еще надо начинать с html, head, body и т.п. ;) а еще смешивать так php и html -- это быдлокодерство и надо использовать шаблоны. да и валидацию оно не пройдет ;) да?  
@Павел Вершинин в условии не было сказано про &другие=параметры ;) см. выше

    <a href='?menu' class='menu <?=(isset($_GET['menu'])?"active":"")?>'>Меню</a>